# Does db.Query return ErrNoRows?

Tags: go

I can't seem to get ErrNoRows from my db.query when a sql query is expected to return no results.

```
results, err := database.Query("SELECT title FROM accountProject WHERE accountID=? AND MATCH(title) AGAINST(?)", accountID, query)
if err != nil {
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return errProjectDoesNotExist
    }
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The value [sql.ErrNoRows](https://godoc.org/database/sql#ErrNoRows) is not returned from [DB.Query](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.Query) or [DB.QueryContext](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.QueryContext). The first call to [Rows.Next](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Rows.Next) returns false when the result set has no rows.

The value [sql.ErrNoRows](https://godoc.org/database/sql#ErrNoRows) is returned from a call to [Row.Scan](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Row.Scan) on a placeholder row returned from [DB.QueryRow](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.QueryRow) or [DB.QueryRowContext](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.QueryRowContext). The DB.QueryRow* methods return a placeholder row on error instead of returning an error directly.

If the application is looking for zero or one rows, use QueryRow instead of Query.

```
row := database.QueryRow("SELECT title FROM accountProject WHERE accountID=? AND MATCH(title) AGAINST(?)", accountID, query)
err := row.Scan( .... address of variables here ... )
if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
    return errProjectDoesNotExist
} else if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Comment: "QueryRow always returns a non-nil value. Errors are deferred until Row's Scan method is called." There should be no err return from QueryRow.